# Style a h2-Element individually even though it is inside a div affected by flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I divided my page in sections, one of the sections contains a h2-Tag (the title of the section) and a div (that contains a p-Tag).
I want the text to be perfectly centered inside the section, because of that, I've used flex to center the element.
Now I need the title to be aligned on the left side (see image for better explanation).
https://ibb.co/b5DSpT
 If I add it to the div affected by the flex-property the styling is completely wrong. If I remove it from the div, the text isn't perfectly centered anymore, because the h2-tag occupies a small amount of the section.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]. If you continue to ask poor quality and downvoted questions, you will get a [question ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use flex. Check the code below.

```css
.wrapper{
  padding:25px;
  background:#d0e1d9;
}

.title{
  color:#000;
  font-size:20px;
  margin:0 0 25px 0;
  
}

.section{
  padding:50px 25px;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:20px;
  background:#e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">Uber uns</div>
  <div class="section">This is the Div with the Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked great :) If I want now, that the "wrapper"-div is also vertically centered (his parent is a section), what should I do?

Comment: @mike I am not sure what you mean, can you send me some picture that can give me better explanation, in mean time try to play with property display:inline-block :)